# How to create a utility method for checking a webElement presence on a webpage in PageObjectModel pattern

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to create a utility method for checking a webElement presence on a webPage in POM framework . i can use the logic of driver.findelements(By.(xpath)/Id/css stc) and check for size . If size is >0 element is present . But In this case i can not pass a PageFactory Webelement as an parameter as findelements only takes a String as parameter but not a webelement . So i want to pass the pagefactory webelement to the utility method and check for presence of a webelement

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you are using Java for this answer, and that you have code that looks like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "foo")    
WebElement element;
```

You are going to find it problematic to create a utility method that does this because a `WebElement` object does not provide a way to extract the locator that was used to generate it.  You have a couple of options I can think of.

**Option 1**

Change your PageFactory implementation to generate a `WebElement` list rather than a single `WebElement`

```
@FindBy(id = "foo")    
List<WebElement> allElements;
```

The downside to this is that you will obviously need to perform an `allElements.get(0)` to get the initial element out of this object when you use it in your page object.

**Option 2**

Switch from PageFactory to using the Query object.  This is a small library that I wrote to get around various problems that I was having with the Java PageFactory.  The code is [available on Github](https://github.com/ardesco/query) and the library is available in Maven Central (See the README.md on Github for usage instructions, setup is very similar to PageFactory).  This will let you define your elements like so:

```
Query query = new Query().defaultLocator(By.id("foo"));
```

You now have the ability to pull out a WebElement, or a list of Webelements using the above object:

```
WebElement soloElement = query.findWebElement();
List<WebElement> allElements = query.findWebElements();
```

So for your specific problem you would be able to perform a check like so:

```
if(query.findWebElements().size() > 0){
    //Do Something
}
```

It will also let you pull out the original locator for use in utility functions, or explicit waits if required

```
By originalLocator = query.by()
```